# Selenium test to maximize window

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nwjs

I'm trying to create a test for an application using nw.js that maximizes the window.

I've tried using:

**driver.manage().window().maximize();**

This throws this error:  Uncaught WebDriverError: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Browser window not found"}

I've not been able to find any info on this error through googling, regardless I would prefer not to use this method as it feels a bit hacky, as the point of the test is to maximize the window in a user setting.

Next I had the idea of using keyboard shortcuts alt+space or windows+up arrow:

**driver.actions().sendKeys(Key.chord(Key.ALT, Key.SPACE)).perform();**

This just doesn't seem to do anything(the syntax seems fine as using something like CTRL + F works). Is this because it's a windows feature and not manipulatable by selenium? And through my research it seems pressing the windows key may also not be possible with selenium.

Appreciate any advice!

Comment: Can you show more of your code: like the creation of the driver